# Connect to RDS instance from VPC outside region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm trying to add the ability to connect to my RDS instance from servers I brought up in a new region (still in an EC2 VPC). I know I can do this by bringing up a bastion server, or creating two extra boxes and running a VPN through them, but I'm wondering: is there a simpler way of doing this? Is there no way to just allow boxes in a security group in one region access to an RDS in another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the security group to an IP in another region, but you cannot open it to a security group in another region.

VPN is probably the safest way to do this, but you would want to closely monitor your VPN instances in case they fail.

If you don't need write access, you can create a multi region read replica. For performance this may be a good idea to use in addition to writing to the master.

Comment: Opening to an ip in another region doesn't seem to work for RDS. I still get `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'some-server.aws.com' (110)`, even when I open up to 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: Is anything filtering outbound connections? Can you connect from your local machine?

Comment: Figured it out. For RDS there's a separate layer of "Publicly Accessible" that you have to explicitly enable for this as well (and allow DNS resolution through your VPC if that's not setup already). Unless you make your RDS publicly accessible, you can add 0.0.0.0/0 to your security group and still be denied access. @datasage, feel free to add this to your answer so the next guy sees it, if you agree, and thanks for the help!